# Simplifying Inequality Involving $\sigma$, $\beta$ and $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, functional-inequalities

Given that $\sigma>0$, $\beta>0$, $x>0$ and $\sigma>\beta$, there are a couple of simplifications I cant derive:
$$1.\,\,\sigma \geq x\,\,\,\,and\,\,\,\,\sigma\beta\geq x\,\,\,\,to\,\,\,\,x\leq\beta$$
$$2.\,\,\sigma \geq x\,\,\,\,and\,\,\,\,\sigma\beta< x\,\,\,\,to\,\,\,\,\beta< x\leq\sigma$$

I have tried using multiplication and division but cant figure out how to arrive to the final answer. Please help. Thanks

Comment: If $\sigma > \beta$, why in $(2)$ do you have $\beta \leq x \leq \sigma$?

Comment: @AlexSilva i dont think so there is anything wrong with $(2)$

Comment: Nothing. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is *not* true: $\sigma = 2, \beta = \frac{1}{2}, x = 1.$

Second one is also *not* true: $\sigma = \frac{1}{2}, \beta = \frac{2}{5}, x = \frac{3}{10}.$

Comment: why is the first one not true? @Krish

Comment: $\sigma > \beta, \sigma > x, \sigma \beta = x$ but $x > \beta$ where $\sigma = 2, \beta = \frac{1}{2}, x = 1.$

Comment: a little confusion: do you mean $\sigma \geq x, \sigma \beta \geq x \Rightarrow x \leq \beta$? because that's what I assumed.

Comment: yes, thats what i meant @Krish

Comment: did you get it? feel free to ask if you have any confusion.

Comment: yes i get it. thank you very much :D